# Как привязать аккаунт GitHub к организации?

Tags: github

Мне нужно создать аккаунт на Гитхабе, но проблема в том что я хочу выбрать платный план. Для того что-бы оплатить этот план нужно ввести данные счета, а он принадлежит компании в которой я работаю. И вот собственно вопрос, как провести оплату от имени компании и что-бы аккаунт был закреплен за ней при дальнейшей работе. Или у меня есть возможность только создать свой собственный аккаунт с выбранным планом.

Comment: Регистрируй новый аккаунт на `email` организации, оплачивай со счета компании план, PROFIT!!!